# Loading a Java class just only once during Mule flow initialization

Tags: spring, mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

I have a java component in my mule flow, which does some security validation.

And every time it downloads a public key from internet, as per the library I use, the library itself caches the file. But I think, because I use this library within onCall() method in my mule flow, it still loads the class for every message. (if I understand it right) . So it ends up calling public key over the internet everytime.

I am was wondering if there is any other method other onCall() I can use ? Or is there any other approach I can take ?

I can in fact download the file only once using a mule flow itself, but for the moment I dont want to refactor the existing class too much.

Regards
Guru

Comment: Check if this helps ; https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/invoke-component-reference

Comment: Good one, let me give it a try. (an another alternative to onCall() )

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Spring bean and let Spring manage it as a singleton

First create the bean in one of the flow xml files:

```
<spring:bean id="securityManager" scope="singleton" class="com.blah.la.di.da.SecurityManagerImpl" >
 <spring:constructor-arg name="dao" ref="backingDaoBean" />
</spring:bean>
```

And then use the java component, defining the object as a Object, select core:spring-object type, and select the bean you defined from the list of Spring beans.

You can still use the onCall() method as the entrypoint